# What is the problem that comes next if I use the overlay Without position absolute and top left right bottom 0?

Tags: html, css, position, overlay

> What is the problem that comes next if I use the overlay
> Without `position absolute`  and `top` `left` `right` `bottom` ; `0` ?

```
<div class="home">                                                       
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```
.home {
  background: url(../imgs/background/background1.webp) ;
  background-size:cover ;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0,0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

> I just used

```
.overlay {
  background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6w3E.jpg)

> The same result can be obtained now .

Source. [W3schools How TO - Overlay](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - what do you mean by "effect" and "comes next"?

Comment: Try adding some content to your page and you will see that the effect is very different if you omit `position: absolute` or `fixed`: https://jsfiddle.net/c5haqxmL/1/

Comment: Why do we use position absolute and top left right bottom 0 if we only use width: 100%; and  height: 100%;  
it gives the same result @Johannes

Comment: if you don't set top/left/right/bottom you will fail into the *static position*. In some cases, it's the same as defining top/left but not always (read the duplicate for more details)